# Invalid keystore format exception when loading keystore file

Tags: java

I'm using the below code to attempt to load a keystore file and I'm getting an java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format Exception. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this or what is causing the issue?

**Load Keystore File:**

```
final FileInputStream keyFile = new FileInputStream(filePath
                    + "key.p7b");
            final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            String storepass = "pwd";
            keyStore.load(keyFile, storepass.toCharArray());
```

**Exception:**

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:633)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:38)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1185)
```

Comment: Why should p7b be a valid keystore?

Comment: that was the keystore file I was sent..

Comment: If that's a keystore file you were sent, how did you try generating a new version of it?

Comment: ignore that statement, I don't have control over the keystore file creation, just the loading of the file.

Comment: p7b is a certificate file, not a keystore file.  You must convert it first.  Apparently OpenSSL can help with that.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - why don't you add that as an answer so I can accept it as that was the issue.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On request, my comment as an answer:

p7b is a certificate file, not a keystore file. You must convert it first. Apparently OpenSSL can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I have a problema like that when I try to create a keystore file with a Sun/Oracle JDK in Portuguese... The portuguese version of JDK (or my Windows PT-BR, I don't know yet) have this bug... I needed to make the keystore file in an English operational system.